# How to fix syntax error, "Missed semicolon", but the semicolon is there?

Tags: javascript, css

I am getting a syntax error for missed semicolon.  I do not see where I am missing one.

I am new to coding. I am trying to adjust the size of an image that is generated by an Api.  The picture currently shows in random sizes which throws the page off.  So I have tried googling, searching for code help and rewriting the code.

This is the error:

```
/src/index.css (./node_modules/css-loader??ref--6-oneOf-3- 
1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!./src/index.css)
Syntax error: Missed semicolon (2:17)

    1 | img src {
  > 2 |     max-height: 25%
      |                 ^
    3 |     max-width: 25%
```

This is the actual code:

```
img src {
max-height: 25%;
max-width: 25%;
}
```

Comment: can you post line 2 of index.css

Comment: The CSS rules end with semicolons. The error contains the code without semicolons, but you posted code with semicolons. There seems a discrepancy. If you're using a bundler such as webpack, try to see from where it gets your CSS.

Comment: I removed src from after img and the same error appeared.  Line 2 is the max-height: 25%;

Comment: The issue most likely is somewhere else in the css file.The syntax parser is mistakenly indicating the line number (may be even the error message itself, maybe the actual issue is not a missing semicolon at all).Welcome to programming.

Answer (score 3):

Your selection syntax is new to me. If you are selecting the image's `src` attribute, try

```
img[src] {
max-height: 25%;
max-width: 25%;
}
```

The above example will allow you to select any image with a `src` attribute.

If this does not remedy the problem, please post a larger chunk of your CSS.